# open Source REST API monitoring tool for Web Services

Tags: rest, api, alert, monitoring, free

I am looking for an Open Source API monitoring tool for RESTful Web service.
Like whether the API is live, down, the performance of the API, Alert by email or phone call when a REST API is down.

I have seen many licensed API monitoring tools. But I am looking for free opensource product and a good one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I recommend Postman monitoring. It's free, you can set up Email alerts, view average response time and average success time.